# What is "Fire Group 3" and how can I use it?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

In Space Pirates and Zombies, in the options screen I see keybindings for fire groups 1, 2 and 3. By experimentation, group one and two correspond to the normal left-right mouse button weapons, which seem to be shooters and launchers respectively. The group 3 key doesn't seem to do anything.

What is group 3, and is there a way to configure which weapons belong to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to an answer posted on the [SPAZ](http://www.spacepiratesandzombies.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=1295) forums:

> In the advanced section you can change around what mouse buttons fire
>   beams, launchers, and shuttles per ship. They are at the very bottom
>   of the advance tactics popup.

This indicates that the third option is shuttles.  This is backed up by the Wikipedia article (emphasis mine):

> Left mouse fires main weapons, right button fire alternative weapons
>   (Such as rockets) and the **middle button launches Shuttles filled with marines**.

It looks like you may need modules to access this option (which may be why it does nothing for you). The modules I can find are the [Suicide Cannon](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Suicide_Cannon) and the [Grunt Shuttle](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Grunt_Shuttle)

Comment: I also found that each weapon type (beams, cannons, launchers, squads) can be bound to any of the weapon groups through the advanced tactics screen. Though it doesn't seem possible to bind weapons from the same type to different weapon groups.